# Swig: convert member variable (pointer to value) to python list

Tags: python, swig

I have a C++ struct with two member variables.  One is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory which contains an array of objects.  The second is an integer with the number of objects in the array.

I have a function which takes an instance of the struct and fills in the two member variables.

I can wrap this just fine and use it from Python with the exception of not being able to iterate over the allocated array.  It is an opaque pointer to Python and I need to be able to access the elements of the array.  How do I do this?

Assume the struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int numElements;
    Result *results;
} ResultList;
```

and the function looks like this:

```
void populateResults(ResultList *);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like this is an example of where the `%extend` keyword is used.  I added the following after the declaration of the `ResultsList` struct:

```
%extend ResultsList {
    Result& __getitem__(int idx) { return $self->results[idx]; }
}
```

It seems to be working.  I can now iterate through the list.  I think the next step is to turn it into an iterable object by implementing the `__next__` and `__iter__` functions as well.